# How to input the border of a matrix?

Tags: c, matrix

I'm having trouble filling a matrix in the way it's shown in the image below.
The matrix must be NxN with N an even number.

[image: Example]

I think the best way to do it is by using two `for` inside a `while`. Something like this:

```
int a=0, c=1, i, j, flag=0, map[N][N] //N with a #define

//First I input my matrix with 0.

for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    for (j=0; j<N; j++)
        map[i][j]=0;

//Here I fill the matrix
while(!flag){

    for(j=a; j<N-a; j++){
        map[i][j]=c;
        c++;
    }
    for(i=a+1; i<N-a; i++){
        map[i][j]=c;
        c++;
    }
    for(j=N-a-1; j>=a; j--){
        map[i][j]=c;
        c++;
    }
    for(i=N-a-1; i>a+1; i--){
        if(map[i][j]==0){
            map[i][j]=c;
            c++;
        }
        else if(map[i][j]!=0)
            flag=1;
    }
c=1;
a++;
}
```

The problem is that id doesn't really work... Could you help me? Thanks

Comment: You are asking about printing. But your code is not printing anything.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I just inserted the part where I have to fill the matrix here

Comment: How is it relevant to your problem? (BTW *what* is the problem?)

Comment: @EugeneSh. The problem is that I cannot input the matrix the way it is requested.

Comment: But where is the input? Do you mean "initialize" instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way without modifying much of your code is as follows:

```
 #define N 4
 #include<stdio.h>

  int a=0, c=1, i, j, flag=0, map[N][N]; //N with a #define


    main() {

   //First I input my matrix with 0.
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        for (j=0; j<N; j++)
            map[i][j]=0;

    i=0;
    //Here I fill the matrix
    while(!flag){

        for(j=a; j<N-a; j++){
            map[i][j]=c;
            c++;
        }
        j--;
        for(i=a+1; i<N-a-1; i++){
            map[i][j]=c;
            c++;
        }
        for(j=N-a-1; j>=a; j--){
            map[i][j]=c;
            c++;
        }
        j++;
        for(i=N-a-1; i>=a+1; i--){
            if(map[i][j]==0){
                map[i][j]=c;
                c++;
            }
        }
        if(map[i+1][j+1]!=0)
            flag=1;

        c=1;
        a++;
        i++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            printf("%d ",map[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    }
```

Here `N` is set as `4`. So output is as follows:

```
1 2 3 4
12 1 2 5
11 4 3 6
10 9 8 7
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly the kind of correction I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You have two types of issues:

1. You don't properly reset `i` or `j` before each of the 4 for-loops within the while-loop. Because of that, you're usually going out-of-bounds when attempting to fill the matrix.
2. Your `flag` never gets set to 1, since the for-loop it's in will never run once the matrix is filled (trace through your code on paper to see exactly why). Now, with your for-loop bounds, you don't actually need a `flag` to keep track of when you're done filling the matrix.

Taking those points into account, your modified code could look like this:

```
int a=0, c=1, i, j, map[N][N] //N with a #define

// (no need to fill your matrix with zeros; your matrix will be filled when your while-loop below ends)

//Here I fill the matrix
while(a < N/2){ // <- stop filling the matrix once a == N/2

    i = a; // <- set i, otherwise the for-loop below will use i=undefined on the first iteration (or i=N if you keep the zeroing code above)

    for(j=a; j<N-a; j++){
        map[i][j]=c;
        c++;
    }

    j = N-a-1; // <- set j, otherwise the for-loop below will use j=N-a, which is out-of-bounds on the first iteration

    for(i=a+1; i<N-a; i++){
        map[i][j]=c;
        c++;
    }

    i = N-a-1; // <- set i, otherwise the for-loop below will use i=N-a, which, again, is out-of-bounds on the first iteration

    for(j=N-a-2; j>=a; j--){ // <- set j=N-a-2 instead of j=N-a-1 to avoid overwriting existing elements of the map
        map[i][j]=c;
        c++;
    }

    j = a; // <- set j, otherwise the for-loop below will use j=a-1, which is out-of-bounds on the first iteration

    for(i=N-a-2; i>a+1; i--){ // <- set i=N-a-2 instead of i=N-a-1 to avoid overwriting existing elements of the map
        // (no need to check if an element is 0)            

        map[i][j]=c;
        c++;
    }
c=1;
a++;
}
```